# Map in product detail page

Tags: product-view, google-map

My store sell products of other stores and I would like to know how can i set a map, from Google Maps for example, in product detail page like the image below?

[image: e.g. image]

Thanks.

Comment: Does every product page need such a map? Does the map have to point to the same location for all products of your store? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Go to google maps and enter your desired location now click on settings button which is in bottom right [image]

select `share or embeded maps->embed map` option select your desired `size` copy the `<iframe>` code.

Now goto `CMS->static Blocks` create a new block and paste the `<iframe>` code in content section.

now call this static block in your product page using `catalog.xml` file in this way

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="cms/block" name="your_block_name">
  <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>your_block_id</block_id>
  </action>
</block>
</reference>
```

Comment: It's working. Thanks dude :) Just one more question. Is it possible to create a attribute and then set this attribute on product detail page? Thanks again.

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I created un attribute that call "maps". Then i added the code: <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getmaps()), 'maps') ?> into view.phtml file (app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml) and worked. :)